# getLogoutUrl is not working with facebook graphp api using php codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My facebook php sdk getLogoutUrl is not working when i click on my logout url.
it takes me back to my given redirect url but it does not destroy my facebook session i can still see my var_dump($fb_data) array on my page and logout url.

Here is my code i am using codeigniter
My lib_login library function facebook code

```
 public function facebook()
    {
        $facebook_default_scope = explode(',', $this->ci->config->item("facebook_default_scope"));
        $facebook_app_id = $this->ci->config->item("facebook_app_id");
        $facebook_api_secret = $this->ci->config->item("facebook_api_secret");

        // init app with app id and secret
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($facebook_app_id, $facebook_api_secret);

        // login helper with redirect_uri
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(site_url('login/facebook'));
        // see if a existing session exists
        if (isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])) {
            // create new session from saved access_token
            $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);

            // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
            try {
                if (!$session->validate()) {
                    $session = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // catch any exceptions
                $session = null;
            }
        }

        if (!isset($session) || $session === null) {
            // no session exists

            try {
                $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
            } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
                // When Facebook returns an error
                // handle this better in production code
                print_r($ex);
            } catch(Exception $ex) {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
                // handle this better in production code
                print_r($ex);
            }
        }

        // see if we have a session
        if (isset($session)) {
            // save the session
            $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
            // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
            $session = new FacebookSession($session->getToken());

            // graph api request for user data
            $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,name,accounts{access_token,category,name,id,perms},permissions');
            $response = $request->execute();
            // get response
            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
            $logoutUrl = site_url('login');
            $fb_data = array(
                'me' => $graphObject,
                'loginUrl' => $helper->getLoginUrl($facebook_default_scope),
                'logoutUrl' => $helper->getLogoutUrl($session,$logoutUrl),
           );
            $this->ci->session->set_userdata('fb_data', $fb_data);

        } else {
            $fb_data = array(
                'me' => null,
                'loginUrl' => $helper->getLoginUrl($facebook_default_scope),
                'logoutUrl' => $helper->getLogoutUrl($session,$logoutUrl),
           );
            $this->ci->session->set_userdata('fb_data', $fb_data);
        }

        return $fb_data;
    }
```

Here is my function of my controller

```
 public function facebook()
    {
        $fb_data = $this->lib_login->facebook();


        if (isset($fb_data['me'])) {
            echo "<pre>";
             var_dump($fb_data);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo '<a href="' . $fb_data['logoutUrl'] . '">logout</a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="' . $fb_data['loginUrl'] . '">Login</a>';
        }
    }
```

When ever i login to my account using this code then the logout url and $fb_data array appears on my page but when i logout and refresh my page it is still their.Can some one tell what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: You would like to make one page or method where you would unset `fb_token` and than pass `header('Location: login.php');` or in CI `redirect('controller/method', 'refresh');`

Comment: @Tpojka i just want to destroy Facebook session when i click on logut url it should take me to login page.if i go to login/facebook method uri then it should show me a login url not the var_dump($fb_data);

Comment: Recently I saw google auth video series and those are very similar by using (Google and Facebook) and I can tell that you need to unset created session. Check [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDs1_FvpqtM).

Comment: @Tpojka this is for google i need this for facebook :(

Comment: So follow example and unset fb session as I wrote in first comment. 2¢

Comment: I am beginner so little bit code would be a great help for me...

Comment: Which library is used (link)?

Comment: https://github.com/appleboy/codeigniter-facebook-php-sdk-v4

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'lib_login'));
        $this->fb_data = $this->lib_login->facebook();
    }
    /**
     * facebook login
     *
     * @return void
     * @author appleboy
     **/
    public function facebook()
    {
        // check login data
        if (isset($this->fb_data['me'])) {
            var_dump($this->fb_data);
        } else {
            echo '<a href="' . $this->fb_data['loginUrl'] . '">Login</a>';
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        if ( isset($this->fb_data['me']) ) {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('fb_data');
        }
        redirect('login/facebook', 'refresh');
    }

}
/* End of file login.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/login.php */
```

Comment: It is redirecting me redirect('login/facebook','refresh'); but it is still showing me the value in var_dump($fb_data['me']); on the page...so logout is still not working

Comment: Are you using other tabs with FB maybe?

Comment: No no other tabs the problem is you unseting the CI Session data not Facebook session data $this->session->unset_userdata('fb_data');

Comment: Maybe something mixed up during code change. Delete manually session from browser. Nad than try again.

Comment: is their any way where we can $fb_data = $this->lib_login->facebook(); only get this value only one time so that we don;t have to define it every time in our two functions

Comment: Include [this part of code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/4.0.0) into your library for logout. p.s. I changed code to avoid repetition.